# C# WPF Dynamically events to array of buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, arrays

I would like to know how to make a `Array` of `Buttons`, every `Button` with its specific content, location and the most important action. From my knowledge a way to do that is this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{             
    _arr[i] = new Button();
    _arr[i].Height = 25;
    _arr[i].Width = 25;
    _arr[i].Content = Convert.ToString(randomnumber);

    _arr[i].Margin = new Thickness(30,0,150,0);
    _arr[i].Click += (a, b) =>
    { 
        do something
    } 
}
```

So my actually question is: Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: This looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your class `MyButton` which will hold `Width`, `Height`, `Content`, `IsDefault` and other things that you may consider useful. Put `ItemsControl` control, bind `ItemsSource` to your `List<MyButton>` and you can style `ItemsPanel` apply your `DataTemplate`. Action can also be bound via `Command` to each button from your class or you can have one action inside which you check which button has been pressed and react.

Answer (score 0):

Put your buttons within a `StackPanel` or a `Grid` or any `Panel`, and handle the `ButtonBase.Click` event of this Panel. So just one event handler. In the event handler, you might cast the `OriginalSource` of the `RoutedEventArg` to a Button, then identify the button with its index within the array, or its Content, or its Name, or Tag.